# libjpeg: process all scanlines once

Tags: c, jpeg, libjpeg

I use jpeg library v8d from [Independent JPEG Group](http://www.ijg.org/) and I want to change the way jpeg decompression reads and processes data.

In the djpeg `main()`, only one scanline/row at a time is read and processed in each `jpeg_read_scanlines()` call. So, to read entire image this functions is called until all lines are read and processed:

```
  while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) { 
    num_scanlines = jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, dest_mgr->buffer,
                    dest_mgr->buffer_height); //read and process
    (*dest_mgr->put_pixel_rows) (&cinfo, dest_mgr, num_scanlines); //write to file
  }
```

But I would like to read the entire image once and store it in the memory and then process the entire image from memory. By reading `libjpeg.txt`, I found out this is possible: "You can process an entire image in one call if you have it all in memory, but usually it's simplest to process one scanline at a time."

Even though I made some progress, I couldn't make it completely work. I can now read a couple of rows once by increasing `pub.buffer_height` value and `pub.buffer` size, but no matter how large `pub.buffer_height` and `pub.buffer` are, only a couple of lines are read in each `jpeg_read_scanlines()` call. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This is my experience too.  Just keep looping until you have the whole image, then you can process the whole image at once after the loop is done.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, This does not work, since the buffer is overwritten in each loop iteration.

Comment: It does work, and I've done it.  In each iteration, you pass a pointer to the first unread scan line in your buffer.  At the end of the loop, every scan line has been read and the buffer is full.

Comment: Would you put your pseudo code? I am a little bit confused because jpeg_read_scanlines does read AND process data. So I don't know where I can draw a line between reading data and processing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> only a couple of lines are read in each `jpeg_read_scanlines()`

Yes, so you call it in a loop.  Here's a loop that grabs one scanline at a time:

```
unsigned char *rowp[1], *pixdata = ...;
unsigned rowbytes = ..., height = ...;

while (cinfo.output_scanline < height) {
    rowp[0] = pixdata + cinfo.output_scanline * rowbytes;
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, rowp, 1);
}
```

Once the loop exits, you have the entire image.

Comment: This makes sense but I think `jpeg_read_scanlines()` both reads the image and processes the image. Am I mistaken? I think all compute-intensive functions such DCT are called inside jpeg_read_scanlines. Is it right? I'd like to decouple IO operations such as reading the input image file and compute-intensive functions such as DCT.

Comment: @aminfar: The above code was copied from a project of mine which does **exactly what you are talking about:** (1) it reads the file, then (2) it decodes the JPEG using the above code, then (3) it processes the resulting raster image.  The above code is step (2), and it does not perform any IO at all if LibJPEG is set up correctly.  Steps (1) and (3) do not involve LibJPEG, I'm hoping you already know how to read a file and what you want to do with it once it's decoded.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think my understanding from libJPEG is different from yours. As far as I know the code you posted does both (1) and (2). Prior to that `while` loop, only image header file is read and the image itself is read row by row by one of the helper functions that is called inside `jpeg_read_scanlines()`. Anyway, maybe I haven't setup the libJPEG correctly or may be I am don't understand it right.

Comment: @aminfar: It's kind of hard to help because you are actually asking two completely different questions.  **Question 1:** How do you read an entire image at a time from LibJPEG?  **Answer 1:** Use the loop I posted. **Question 2:** How do I make the IO finish before decoding the image?  **Answer 2:** Do all of your IO before you even touch LibJPEG.  LibJPEG will only do IO if you tell it to do IO.  This is all explained quite thoroughly in the docs, in the section "Compressed data handling".

Comment: I used information on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280756/libjpeg-ver-6b-jpeg-stdio-src-vs-jpeg-mem-src) and your answer and I was finally able to get what I wanted. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.